# secure google places api key

Tags: html, reactjs, dotenv

I have HTML project with React elements (passing react script tags in html) and I need to secure api key in script with google map url. I'm new to this and I'm not sure if it's even possible? 
I tried `'dotenv'` and `'dotenv webpack'`.

As a result: I can access my API-KEY defined in .env, but only in terminal by running `$ node -r dotenv/config ./src/index.js`

```js
// ./src/index.js
console.log(process.env.API_KEY)
```

I tried to store it in a variable and insert a new script tag into HTML like so:

```js
// ./src/index.js
require('dotenv-webpack');

var newScript = document.createElement("script");
newScript.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.S3_API}&libraries=places`;
newScript.type = "text/javascript";
target.appendChild(newScript);
```

I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at index.js`

I also tried `HtmlWebpackPlugin`:

```js
// ./webpack.config.js
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      path: './.env', // Path to .env file (this is the default)
      safe: true
      }), // load .env.example (defaults to "false" which does not use dotenv-safe))
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: './web/web.html',
          title: 'Custom template using html-loader',
          environment: {
            'GOOGLE_PLACES_API': process.env.GOOGLE_PLACES_API;
          })
    ]
};
```

```html
<!-- ./web/web.html -->
...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.environment %>&libraries=places"></script>

...
```

Would appreciate any help or suggestions

Comment: Fundamentally, if you want to make API requests *from the browser*, then the API key must be visible in the browser somehow, which means your server will need to send it to the browser, which means you are by definition publicly exposing your API key. There's no way to "secure" it. — There are Google APIs that are meant to be used that way, and the API key is not intended to be "secured". There may be other APIs you shouldn't access from a browser in the first place using a private key only.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to secure your API keys, you don't have to hide them
Instead, Restrict your API keys: You can best protect your API key by restricting it to specific IP addresses, referrer URLs or mobile apps, and specific APIs, as this significantly reduces the impact of a key compromise.

In this link, you can find more details about [Google API Keys best practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices)